# Will Battlepack quantity or quality lead to more puzzle pieces?

Tags: battlefield-1

I periodically buy battlepack's with my free scraps in battlefield 1, because there is little else to do with them, except buy really expensive weapons.  This way I can eventually get all the melee weapon puzzle pieces to complete my weapons collection.

[image: Expensive battlepack]

I wonder, though, whether it is better to buy as many of the cheapest battlepacks as I can afford or does it make more sense to buy as many of the most expensive battlepacks as I can afford if I want to maximize my chances of receiving puzzle pieces over time.

The more expense battlepacks advertise that they are more likely to contain puzzle pieces, but they are also more expensive so less can be bought, thus its not clear which path leads to the best odds of receiving a puzzle piece over time.

Which battlepack buying strategy is better, quantity or quality, when attempting to complete melee weapon puzzles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my personal experience, you are better off saving until you can afford the higher quality packs. Even though the other packs are cheaper you tend to get more from only a few the higher quality packs than you do from opening a lot more of the lower quality.

Comment: Yeah, in this game I only buy the most expensive ones, in contrast to battlefront where i get the cheapest first.